# Setting up multiple ASP.NET Core sites in Linux CentOS Apache subdomains

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, asp.net-core, centos

I am setting up a solution in Linux (CentOS Apache) that consists of 3 different ASP.NET Core 6 projects that each live within their subdomain, namely;

1. The Webclient project (should be accessed directly from myexample.com)
2. The IdentityServer project (member.myexample.com)
3. The API project (api.example.com)

How on earth do I config Apache/Linux/CentOS so that it treats each subdomain like an "isolated" ASP.NET Core 6 application listening to their respective subdomain?

That is, for example: if I go to api.example.com, then the API project should load.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [Does this link useful to you ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/942587/how-to-configure-multiple-apache-subdomains-for-net-core-2-0-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @JasonPan: Thanks, it does help a little bit on the way! It turns out that we needed to set different ports for each subdomain (eg.: 5000, 5001, 5002) and then configure individual services correctly so that they would work within their "domain" so to say.